# Python Check if a string is there in a sentence from a list of strings

Tags: python, substring, match, python-3.7

I have a list of words like `substring = ["one","multiple words"]` from which i want to check if a sentence contains any of these words.

```
sentence1 = 'This Sentence has ONE word'
sentence2 = ' This sentence has Multiple Words'
```

My code to check using any operator:

```
any(sentence1.lower() in s for s in substring)
```

This is giving me false even if the word is present in my sentence. I don't want to use regex as it would be an expensive operation for huge data.

Is there any other approach to this?

Comment: @AnswerSeeker While the check may be wrong (as pointed out by others), the use of `any()` seems reasonable.  Why do you say the use is unreasonable/improper?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should reverse your order:

```
any(s in sentence1.lower() for s in substring)
```

you're checking if your substring is a part of your sentence, NOT if your sentence is a part of any of your substrings.

Comment: Yes, i was checking in reverse order. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in other answers, this is what will get you the correct answer if you want to detect substrings:

```
any(s in sentence1.lower() for s in substring)
```

However, if your goal is to find words instead of substrings, this is incorrect. Consider:

```
sentence = "This is an aircraft"
words = ["air", "hi"]
any(w in sentence.lower() for w in words)  # True.
```

The words `"air"` and `"hi"` are not in the sentence, but it returns `True` anyway. Instead, if you want to check for words, you should use:

```
any(w in sentence.lower().split(' ') for w in words)
```

Answer (score 0):

use this scenario.

```
a="Hello Moto"
    a.find("Hello")
```

It will give you an index in return. If the string is not there it will return -1

Comment: I intend to increase my list of sub strings foe which i want to check , that's why i went with any operator